# "Symbol 'cin' can not be resolved" error in Eclipse on OS X

Tags: c++, eclipse, cout, cin

I am just beginning a C++ class and I am working on our first homework. I am using Eclipse and it's giving me some problems. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int first, second;
    cout<< "Type the first number and press enter.\n";
    cin>>first;
    cout << "Type the second number and press enter.\n";
    cin>>second;
    cout<<"The sum of "<<first<<" and "<<second<<" is "<<(first+second)<<", and the product is "<<(first*second)<<endl;
}
```

I am fairly sure that the code is good and should compile and run, but Eclipse is giving me a bunch of errors. For each of the cin and cout statements, I am getting an error which says: "Symbol 'cin'/'cout' could not be resolved." I am also getting an error which says: "symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64."

I am running Mac OS X v10.7.2, GNU Make 3.81, and i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00).

Like I said, I'm new, so if you need more info, just let me know. Thank you.

Comment: It seems that you are trying to build 64bit code and that you don't have the libraries installed for this.

Comment: How would I fix this? I have XCode installed and my computer is 64-bit.

Comment: Thats strange, Lion supports 64 bit...

Comment: You installed "i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2". Try to install (if it exists) the 64 bit package.

Comment: What toolchain did you choose for your project?

Answer (score 1):

I have also had this problem recently, and I have found an easier solution not yet mentioned here.

The problem is that creating a new C++ project in Eclipse with the project type of **"Empty Project"**, creates really just that--an empty project. Eclipse does not configure the project's include directories to use the standard libraries when such an option is selected.

To fix this, **create your project again** but now select the project type of **"Hello World C++ Project"**. This will then tell Eclipse to configure the project's include directories to include the standard libraries from the start, which is what 99% of us users want, anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit old but am gonna answer anyway.. I've faced this problem in netbeans... just try to change the "C" compiler to g++ not gcc :)
If that didn't work check if iostream is really included

Answer (score -1):

4 Suggestions:

1) Try changing `<iostream>` to `<iostream.h>`
2) Build in 32 Bit
3) Try building from command.
4) Try a reinstallation of Xcode.

Comment: <iostream> is correct and is generally used, but specifiying the header extension sometimes resolves strange errors

Comment: Ok -- but if it does, that indicates another problem.

Comment: Your right, but the the problem cannot be properly resolved if it's effects aren't identified. If <iosstream.h> works it would significantly help narrow down the problem